# Spring boot 2.0.1 SpringApplicationBuilder doesnt exists

Tags: java, spring-boot

what is new configurationin Spring boot 2.0.1 SpringApplicationBuilder, that class doesnt exists and configure method too

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {  

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootMainApplication.class);
    }
```

Comment: The class still exists in 2.0.1. Perhaps your build system corrupted a jar file when you upgraded?

Comment: I deleted m2 repository after upload now works fine some collisions i bet